# What are the letters in a XAML Geometry attribute called?

Tags: wpf, drawing, shapes, geometrydrawing

I am defining a XAML `DrawingBrush` resource and I want to draw a custom shape. I found the following `GeometryDrawing` example:

```
<GeometryDrawing Geometry="M0,0.1 L0.1,0 1,0.9, 0.9,1z" Brush="Gray" />
```

What do the `M`, `L`, and `z` letters in the `Geometry` attribute mean? What are they called?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a [StreamGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.streamgeometry.aspx).   It uses something called [Path Markup Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx).  M is start point, L starts a line, Z is close.